# Django user update is not working

Tags: python, django, patch

I have this user serializer:

```
class SimpleUser(models.Model):
    class meta:
        abstract = True

    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=128)
    first_name = models.EmailField(_('first name'), blank=True)

class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SimpleUser
```

And this is my view:

```
class UserView(APIView):
    def patch(self, request, user_id):
        firstname = request.data.get('first_name', '')
        email = request.data.get('email', '')
        password = request.data.get('password', '')

        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        serializer = UserSerializer(instance=user, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I send this json request, but only the `password` and `email` are updated and `first_name` not updated.

```
{
"password":"6524266",
"email":"HH@bb.com",
"first name":"dsfxvxc"
}
```

I get the status `200 OK` and can get the saved object in `serializer.save()`

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set firstname as emailfield

```
first_name = models.EmailField(_('first name'), blank=True)
```

Changes this to CharField or related fields, something like this,

```
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Comment: Thanks, but why now my new pasword is saved in `plain text` instead of `hashed`?

Comment: ooh.. i noticed that but forgot to mention, why you are using your on usermodel instead of django user model ?

Comment: I need to use `usermodel `.

Comment: check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.hashers , if you want to use `SimpleUser` model with password field, then on save use makepassword & check password functions